# openCV Integration with Visual Studio 2013 issue

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

first at all thanks for reading. I was through a lot of tutorials about how to install openCV in VS2013. I think i followed correctly all the steps but finally when i run the console win32 application c++ i got this error:

```
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\openCV\x64\Debug\openCV.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui2410d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_core2410d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'openCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[5168] openCV.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I dont understand why the VS cant load the libraries cause i make all the configs (at least that i think)

My global var is:

```
PATH= "C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin";
```

where open's installed.

Here's my code main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

if (!image.data) // Check for invalid input
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.

waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was reading and the lines above does not mean an error.
And the error -1 was another, that happend cause the code is get int 
if (argc != 2) cause actually does not receive any parameters (error just to do and not to think :P)

So giving an image as parameter everything works perfectly.
Sorry for bother you guys and hope this help for other guy with the same problem :P

Comment: You can submit this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Even if it works, should this: PATH= "C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin";
be with vc12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`vc11` is for VS2012, for VS2013, you should use `vc12`.**

For your case, change

```
PATH= "C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin";
```

to

```
PATH= "C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin";
```

**p.s.:** Also make sure your project is built under `x64` platform.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading and the lines above does not mean an error. And the error -1 was another, that happend cause the code is get int if (argc != 2) cause actually does not receive any parameters (error just to do and not to think :P) So giving an image as parameter everything works perfectly. Sorry for bother you guys and hope this help for other guy with the same problem =)

besides and thanks to @herohuyongtao 
vc11 is for VS2012, for VS2013, you should use vc12.

For your case, change

PATH= "C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin";
to

PATH= "C:\Users\GASTON\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin";
p.s.: Also make sure your project is built under x64 platform.